# Can we order the "All Sites" list on the iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, sorting, communities-list

There appears to be no particular order on the iOS app's "All Sites" list. It is not alphabetical, based on my rep, nor based on popularity:

[image: all_sites]

Am I correct in that the list is unordered? If so, I propose we order it. Preferably by user rep or popularity. Something similar to the side bar:

[image: side_bar]

Comment: It seems that the newly created sites are ordered last.

Comment: It does make it bit of a chore trying to find a particular site, having to scroll to a seemingly random point in the list. I would like to see it ordered alphabetically, in the same way the user's member sites are ordered. Maybe give the user various options on how to order: newly created, popularity, user rep, alphabetically, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of the app.

The sites are now sorted alphabetically to match the top bar.